# Linq two select statements, second one uses first ones result,

Tags: c#, linq

This linq query works well.

```
var qry = context.Boxes
          .GroupBy(k=>k.Box_ID)
          .Select( group => new {
              Box_ID = group.Key,
              TotalA = group.Sum(p => p.A),
              TotalC = group.Sum(p => p.C)
          })
          .Select(p => new {
              Box_ID = p.Kasa_ID,
              TotalA = p.TotalA,
              TotalC = p.TotalC,
              DiffAC = p.TotalA - p.TotalC
          });
```

But, i saw these type select statements, second one uses first select's anonymous type result, written like this:

```
  var qry = context.Boxes
            .GroupBy(k => k.Box_ID)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                Box_ID = group.Key,
                TotalA = group.Sum(p => p.A),
                TotalC = group.Sum(p => p.C)
            })
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Box_ID,  //*** compiler error
                TotalA,  //I'm asking about these 3 lines, is this syntax possible 
                TotalC,  //TotalC = p.TotalC,
                DiffAC = p.TotalA - p.TotalC // calculate
            });
```

comments contains details.

When i try to compile second query, compiler gives me the error "The name 'Box_ID' does not exist in the current contex".

In fact there is no doubt with first syntax, but second one is more readable. How can i use second syntax? or in which condititons i can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        .Select(p => new
        {
            p.Box_ID,
            p.TotalA,
            p.TotalC,
            DiffAC = p.TotalA - p.TotalC // calculate
        });
```